# How to make polyester casting resin?

Tags: polymers

What are the components of and how would one go about making [polyester casting resin](http://www.dickblick.com/products/castincraft-clear-polyester-casting-resin/)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resin_casting, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyester_resin